# RadGrid Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Does anyone know how to remove certain filters from a radGrid. I have the stock ones up and they vary by data type but I don't need all of them just 3 or 4 of them. I used gridfiltermenu but that gets rid of a certain filter from every column. ie: I need equals in one column but not in another. I have tried to sort through this so many ways. Here is what I have - excuse the clutter. Im have the databinded on the backend so I don't have them as individual columns on the front. I tried to get the column by column name but gridfilteringitem among other methods don't accept the names as arguments.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gvPIOList" runat="server" 
        Class="display table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive text-center"
        CellPadding="2" HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True" GroupPanelPosition="Top" Skin="Outlook"
        ShowFooter="True" OnNeedDataSource="gvPIOList_NeedDataSource"
        MasterTableView-RowIndicatorColumn-Visible="false" 
        HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
        AlternatingItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowFilteringByColumn="true"
        MasterTableView-EditFormSettings-EditColumn-FilterListOptions="VaryByDataTypeAllowCustom"
        MasterTableView-EditFormSettings-EditColumn-ShowFilterIcon="false"
        MasterTableView-EditFormSettings-EditColumn-AndCurrentFilterFunction="Contains"
        OnColumnCreated="gvPIOList_ColumnCreated" OnInit="gvPIOList_Init"
        OnItemCreated="gvPIOList_ItemCreated">
            <MasterTableView GroupLoadMode="Server" 
                EditFormSettings-EditColumn-AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"
                EditFormSettings-EditColumn-FilterDelay="1000"
                AllowFilteringByColumn="true"
                EditFormSettings-EditColumn-FilterListOptions="VaryByDataTypeAllowCustom"
                EditFormSettings-EditColumn-ShowFilterIcon="false">
            </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Here is the code:

```
protected void gvPIOList_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridFilterMenu menu = gvPIOList.FilterMenu;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < menu.Items.Count)
    {
        if (menu.Items[i].Text == "NoFilter" || menu.Items[i].Text == "Contains" || menu.Items[i].Text == "Equals" || menu.Items[i].Text == "StartsWith")
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            menu.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code I use:

It works for different data types, you can replace the `column.get_dataType() == "Sytem.Int64"` 
by the name of the column.

Write the values you want to keep in the `in { 'NoFilter': '', 'Contains': '' }` section.

you call this function in the Client settings section of the RadGrid:

aspx:

```
<ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
    <ClientEvents OnFilterMenuShowing="filterMenuShowing" />
</ClientSettings>
<FilterMenu OnClientShowing="MenuShowing" />
```

.js (can be placed directly in the aspx):

```
var column = null;
function MenuShowing(sender, args)
{
if (column == null) return;
var menu = sender; var items = menu.get_items();
if (column.get_dataType() == "System.String")
{
    var i = 0;
    while (i < items.get_count())
    {
        if (!(items.getItem(i).get_value() in { 'NoFilter': '', 'Contains': '' }))
        {
            var item = items.getItem(i);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.set_visible(false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var item = items.getItem(i);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.set_visible(true);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
if (column.get_dataType() == "System.Int64")
{
    var j = 0; while (j < items.get_count())
    {
        if (!(items.getItem(j).get_value() in { 'NoFilter': '', 'EqualTo': '' }))
        {
            var item = items.getItem(j); if (item != null)
                item.set_visible(false);
        }
        else
        {
            var item = items.getItem(j); if (item != null) item.set_visible(true);
        }
        j++;
    }
}
column = null;
menu.repaint();
}
function filterMenuShowing(sender, eventArgs)
{
    column = eventArgs.get_column();
}
```

This is taken from Telerik's website: [Filter Menu Showing](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/how-to/Filtering/reduce-the-filter-menu-options)